# Can you make an AVL Tree of Vectors

Tags: c++, data-structures

Is it possible to implement an AVL tree where each node is a vector? I have tried to find a clear answer to this, but I haven't found anything directly. In order to determine if a vector should be placed to the left or right of another vector, I was going to base this off of the value of the first element in each vector. Does this sound like something that would work?

Comment: Do you mean that the data of the nodes should be a vector? Then why not? It doesn't matter what the data is really, as long as the data could be compared for less-than (for the ordering).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Yes, each node would be a vector. I was thinking this was possible, I just hadn't seen anyone mention it before, so, I thought I was missing something.

Comment: What makes you think you would have any difficulty at all doing this? Did you try and fail?

Comment: @JaMiT This is one of a few different implementations that I am considering. Currently, a binary search is being used each time to find a coordinate and also for related coordinates. So, with this implementation, I can group them all together so, I only have to find the vector of the coordinates once. My project advisor wants me to come up with a quicker way of doing so. I thought of this implementation but found it strange that I didn't see anyone else mention it before.

Comment: Concerning coordinates: If you just want a fast look-up then you may provide a less predicate which compares first, and only if first components are equal, then compares second, and only if second are equal ... and finally compares last components. If you want to consider spatial relationships (somehow), then it's not that simple. Sorting for x may bring coordinates close together which have large distance in y (and/or other components)...

Comment: @Kyler In the words of a corporate giant, Just Do It. Come back with a question if you run into difficulty. *(People don't mention every possible data type for abstract containers because they are designed to handle all kinds of data. The list would just be too long.)*